# how to change aws region while running cdk deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to change the region from us-east-1 to us-east-2 while running the command `cdk deploy`. I have tried `cdk deploy aws://account/region` but nothing positive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your AWS region before running your CDK command:

```
export AWS_REGION=us-east-2
```

Answer (score 0):

one option its define a new profile with the wanted region an use as follow:

```
cdk deploy --profile myProfile
```

**NOTE:**
Be aware that there are services that are cross regions(global) like s3 bucket.

Answer (score -1):

You can add them in as command line args.

```
aws cdk deploy --all --region us-east-1
```